# I need a list of all topics subscribed by a user in grails version 3.3.9 having domain of subscription ,topic,users

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class, grails3

```
 def subscribedTopicOfUser(){
        Users loggedInUser = Users.findByUserName(session.userSession)
        println(loggedInUser)
        def val=loggedInUser.id
        def subscribedTopicOfUser = Subscription.findAllWhere(loggedInUser : loggedInUser)
        println (subscribedTopicOfUser)
```

Comment: From your code I can kind of guess that there is probably a `loggedInUser` property in the `Subscription` class, which is an unusual thing because normally you wouldn't persisted info to a database info about who is logged in.  That aside, there is no mention of where the relationship to a topic comes into play.  Can you show enough of your domain class source code to represent the relationships between those 3 classes?  (you can leave out everything that isn't related to the relationships)

Comment: It looks like `loggedInUser` is just a user ID stored as part of a Subscription (which seems far more normal).  Past that though, I would guess that a subscription has a topic?  Maybe more than one?  Please share domain model per @JeffScottBrown suggestion.  If `Subscription` has a `.topic` field, you could put `*.topic` after that `findAllWhere()` call.

Comment: "It looks like loggedInUser is just a user ID stored as part of a Subscription" - Maybe, but the declared type is `Users`, which is apparently a domain class.